# We can't verify who created this file

Tags: windows, security, group-policy

I am getting this warning

We can't verify who created this file

[image]

I have an exe file which I need to run on startup using GPO.

I found how to either [exclude the whole server](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/489059-open-file-security-warning-we-can-t-verify-who-created-this-file) where the file is or either [exclude the filetype](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4340701d-66fe-4656-a7bb-8cefa49b2e6c/atypical-open-file-security-warning-we-cant-verify-who-created-this-file?forum=w7itprosecurity) (.exe) from the check. UAC is already set to not notify.

I just want to exclude from the check just this single file not the whole server or all the EXEs. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: What exactly is your question?  If you want to trust this file, you need to unblock it, go into the properties of the file in order to do that.

Comment: I am in a business environment this is not possible and either way it's already unblocked.

Comment: If you cannot do it then you will have to have an Administrator trust the file, because it currently isn't trusted, hence the reason you are getting the security warning.  If you are an administrator, or are not authorized to make the change, then you will be unable to resolve the security miss configuration causing this warning.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of options online describing how to fix the issue. Here's the link so hopefully you can find what you need my friend.

[Windows: Disable “Publisher Could Not Be Verified” Messages](https://www.technipages.com/disable-publisher-could-not-be-verified-messages)

> Option 1 – Group Policy Editor

- Hold the Windows Key, then press “R” to bring up the Run dialog box.
- Type `gpedit.msc`, then select “OK“. Go to “User Configuration” >
  Administrative Templates” > “Windows Components” > “Attachment
  Manager“.

  - Open the “Inclusion list for moderate risk file types”
    setting. Set the policy to “Enabled“, then add `*.exe;` or whatever
    the file extension you are using to the “Specify high risk
    extensions” box.

> Option 2 – Registry Tweak

- Hold the Windows Key, then press “R” to bring up the Run dialog box.
- Type `regedit`, then select “OK“.
- Navigate to the following: `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Associations`
- Look for an entry on the right side for `LowRiskFileTypes`. If it doesn’t exist, you will need to create it. To do so, right-click on `FileSystem` and select “New” > “String Value“. Give the value a name of `LowRiskFileTypes`.
- Press the “Enter” key when you are done.
- Right-click the `LowRiskFileTypes` entry and click “Modify“.
- Modify the value by including file extensions, with periods, separated by semi-colons `.bat;.exe` would add batch and executable files.

This should disable the `Publisher Could Not Be Verified` messages from appearing for that file type in the future.

Comment: I don't want to do that for all exe files.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a script where I do the following

add a registry key which adds a specific server into the trusted zone
launch the software
remove the registry key

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\*domainName*\servername" /v * /t REG_DWORD /d 1
sleep 2
pushd \\servername.domain.name\netlogon\software
& .\Software.exe
popd
sleep 2
reg delete "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet 
Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\domainName" /f
```

Comment: If using Group Policy you can add `\\servername.domain.name\netlogon\software` to the policy labeled "*Site to Zone Assignment List*" within **User Configuration/Policies/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Internet Explorer/Internet Control Panel/Security Page** with a value of `1` and that should take care of it too.